# Android install external library

Tags: android, eclipse

I want to use this library https://github.com/koush/ion in my project.But I don't understand how can I install it.I am using Windows 8 and Eclipse.How can I install ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Download that project and put it in workspace of eclipse and import it from work space to eclipse and make it as library project and add it to your project.

Steps to import:

1. Right Click on package explorer
2. Import
3. Existing Project into Workspace
4. And then browse to the location where the project downloaded
5. Import it

Steps to add it as library to your project:

1. Right-click on your project -> Properties
2. In Android->Library section click Add
3. Select recently added project -> OK
4. That's it!

Now you can use it

Comment: Thank you so much.I imported project but I am getting too many errors here you can see:http://prntscr.com/446zlr Why I am getting this errors ?

Comment: It seems that the jars are not imported once clean the project by going to windows-->clean-->select your project-->finish
then refresh your project by pressing F5

Answer (score 1):

You must perform the following steps:

- **Download** ion project code.
- **Import** it in your workspace using eclipse.
- Right click in your current project and select **Properties**. The project properties windows must be opened.
- Select **Android** option.
- Go to the bottom of this tab and you can view the **Library section**.
- **Add the library** dependency using the Add button.

I hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

You are probably better off downloading the jars vs the source.

https://github.com/koush/ion#get-ion

Download those two and place them in the "libs" directory of your project. If that directory does not exist, create it. From with your Eclipse project preferences, you can add those jars as dependencies.